# line by line standard output of subprocess while writing in notepad file

Tags: python

I run a command within a `for` loop, e.g

```
subprocess.run("ipconfig",shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
```

I am getting line by line in the `stdout` while running through IDLE. However, when writing this output to a text file, the output is continuous and not line by line anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should change universal_newlines to True

Comment: May you please provide the full code for the program